# Cannot connect android React Native app to localHost .NET api

Tags: .net, visual-studio, localhost, react-native

I have a React Native app that simply needs to login and subsequently fetch data using the returned access_token. I am trying to debug the error by connecting to the locally hosted .NET api running on localHost:50968. This returns

```
    TypeError: Network request failed
```

I have already enabled the internet permission in the manifext.xml. 
Most of the googling has been saying that i need to change localHost:50968 to my ip address.This has been the closest so far using '192.168.0.2:50968/token but the below is the response.

```
    { type: 'default',
status: 400,
ok: false,
statusText: undefined,
headers: { map: { 'content-length': [ '334'
        ],
connection: [ 'close'
        ],
date: [ 'Thu,
            10 Aug201703: 19: 14 GMT'
        ],
server: [ 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0'
        ],
'content-type': [ 'text/html; charset=us-ascii'
        ]
    }
}, url: 'http: //192.168.0.2:50968/token',
 _bodyInit: 
 '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">\r\n
<HTML>

<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>\r\n
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
</HEAD>\r\n

<BODY>
    <h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>\r\n
    <hr>
    <p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>\r\n
</BODY>

</HTML>\r\n', _bodyText: '
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> \r\n
<HTML>

<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Bad Request
    </TITLE>\r\n
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
</HEAD>\r\n

<BODY>
    <h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>\r\n
    <hr>
    <p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>\r\n
</BODY>

</HTML>\r\n'}
```

I have a breakpoint in Visual Studio waiting for the request but I cannot for the life of me get this to work. 
My code for the fetch is as follows.

Iv tried the these as the URL_LOGIN and neither work. 
'http://localHost:50968/token';
'http://192.168.0.2:50968/token';

```
    fetch(URL_LOGIN, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            //application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        },
        body: data
    }).then((response) => {
        var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response._bodyInit);
        try {
            AsyncStorage.setItem('token', jsonResponse.access_token);
            loginUserSuccess(dispatch, response)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Error while saving to Async Storage ${error.message}`)
            loginUserFailed(dispatch, error)
        }
    }).catch(response => {
       loginUserFailed(dispatch, response)
    });
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ended up finding this. Just in case anybody else has this issue.

http://briannoyesblog.azurewebsites.net/2016/03/06/calling-localhost-web-apis-from-visual-studio-android-emulator/

The best way I found was actually to use this

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti

Saved my behind.

Comment: Use the second link if you are having this issue it is a life saver. Tool is called Conveyor by Keyoti. Thanks for the help!

Comment: +1 for ya. It's been ages I tried to connect my physical device to my local web IIS since `"react-native": "0.60.3"`. And finally, the extension did saved me from always counting on real domain.

Answer (score 0):

Use `10.0.2.2` instead of `localhost`

`http://10.0.2.2:50968/token`

On android localhost maps to the emulator and not your machine.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah I tried this. I get the same response as when I use http://<my ip>:50968/token

Answer (score 0):

In the response you've posted, I noticed it says `url: 'http: //192.168.0.2:50968/token'`, with a space between `http:` and `//`. Are you sure you haven't just incorrectly formatted your URL in `URL_LOGIN`?